# How to use linq to object to hide or show some control in asp.net page

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq, controls, linq-to-objects

I am creating a function to hide all the gridview controls except the control whose name is being passed in the function.

Here `this.Controls` refers to controls present in the page (At compilation error is thrown although). I want to **fetch all the controls of type GridView** with Name property not equal to the one passed in the function.

Now after getting a collection of GridView. I want to hide all the grids

```
private void HideGridView(string gridToShow)
{
    GridView[] result = from control in this.Controls
                 where control.GetType() == typeof(GridView) && control.Name !=gridToShow
                 select control as GridView;

    foreach (var control in result)
        control.Visible = false;
}
```

At comile time it shows me `this.Control` as invalid because it is not a collection.

```
How can I achieve this on a web application
```

**EDIT:**

```
private void HideGridView(string gridToShow)
{
    (from control in this.Controls.OfType<GridView>
     where control.Name !=gridToShow
     select control).ToList().ForEach(gv=>gv.Visible=false);
}
```

*Here is the code I wrote, shows me an error: `GridView` is a type but used like a variable (Compile time error).
And at `where` Invalid Expression Term 'where'*

Comment: Can you re-phrase this in the form of a question, Shantanu? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where does this method exist?  Is it on your page, or in a separate library.  If it is a member of your Page-derived class, it shoudl work fine.  If you put it in a separate library, you'll need to pass the Page in:

```
private void HideGridView(Page page, string gridToShow) 
{ 
    (from control in page.Controls.OfType<GridView>()
     where control.Name !=gridToShow 
      select control).ToList().ForEach(gv=>gv.Visible = false);
 }
```

And it would be called as

```
  HideGridView(this, "VisibleGrid");
```

You can also make it an extension method:

```
static class MyExtensions
{
  public static void HideGridView(this Page page, string gridToShow) 
  { 
       /// same as above.
  }
}
```

then you could call it as:

```
  HideGridView("VisibleGrid");
```

Comment: @MUG4N: No, one equals.  I'm setting it, not comparing it.

Comment: @James: It shows an zigzag error saying GridView is a type but used like a variable.

Comment: Does `Control` have a property `Name`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control_members.aspx

Comment: hmmm `GridView` doesn't either....

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_members.aspx

Comment: @Shantanu: I just fixed a typo, which you may have missed. (Parens at the end of that line)

Comment: @Hunter: Yes you are right I missed both the things Name to be replaced by ID and () in answer of James.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
this.Controls.OfType<GridView>().Where(c => c.ID != gridToShow)
    .ToList().ForEach(gv => gv.Visible = false);
```

And as an extension method:

```
public static void ShowGridView(this Page page, string gridToShow)
{
    page.Controls.OfType<GridView>().Where(c => c.ID != gridToShow)
        .ToList().ForEach(gv => gv.Visible = false);
}
```

which will let you call it like this in your Page_Load:

```
this.Page.ShowGridView("showThisGridView");
```